How are atomic operations exactly implemented on Raspberry Pi Pico RP2040 Cortex M0+ dual core?
I was trying to find out if there are any atomic instructions like fetch_and_add or compare_and_swap supported by ARM Cortex-M0 used in Pi Pico, and I found a thread  explaining that there are no such instructions for Cortex-M0. Instead, for atomicity, one has to rely on a special spin lock peripheral and support available from the C/C++ SDK.
When examining the specific spin lock implementation in sync.h in the SDK, I encountered a couple of questions:
Implementation of spin_lock_blocking: Here, interrupts are first disabled, and then spin_lock_unsafe_blocking is called, which spins on a lock variable and then asserts a memory fence.
Questions:

Disabling the interrupt will definitely stop preemption on the same core, but what ensures that both cores do not attempt to read/modify/write the lock variable simultaneously? In comments they say wait for the other core but how? On some other processors, this job would be done by a test_set instruction inside the while loop, but here it is only reading the pointer value. Is this safe?

What is the purpose of the memory barrier once the lock is acquired?

I'm unclear about the comment inside the spin_lock_unsafe_blocking implementation. What do they mean by 'never block'?


Following code is from sync.h
#define __builtin_expect(x, y) (x)

__force_inline static void spin_lock_unsafe_blocking(spin_lock_t *lock) {
    // Note: we don't do a WFE or anything because, by convention, these spin locks are VERY SHORTLIVED and **NEVER BLOCK** and run
    // with INTERRUPTS disabled (to ensure that)... therefore, nothing on our core could be       blocking us, so we just **need to wait** on another core
    // anyway, which should be finished soon

    while (__builtin_expect(!*lock, 0));
    __mem_fence_acquire();
}

__force_inline static uint32_t spin_lock_blocking(spin_lock_t *lock) {
    uint32_t save = save_and_disable_interrupts();
    spin_lock_unsafe_blocking(lock);
    return save;
}


Just a guess ... spin locks "spin" on a lock. This could be considered "blocking" on the lock (which is what I think you're interpreting this as). But, here, I think blocking could be one of two things: (1) The H/W spinlocks do not stop execution of the CPU if the lock is already taken (as evidenced by the S/W while loop). But if they did this would be "blocking" (and no while would be needed) (2) Blocking is suspending the current task, invoke the task scheduler, run another task, resume when lock available. Probably (1) is the more likely explanation.



Disabling the interrupt will definitely stop preemption on the same core, but what ensures that both cores do not attempt to
read/modify/write the lock variable simultaneously?


Hardware, presumably, for the relevant definition of "at the same time".  For the implementation to be remotely correct, the system's memory controller must provide for reads from and writes to objects of type spin_lock_t (probably an integer) to be performed atomically (even in a memory_order_relaxed sense could be enough). It would not be particularly surprising for that to be a valid assumption on any particular hardware, though it is not safe in general to make such assumptions.

In comments they
say wait for the other core but how?

The while loop cycles until *lock is nonzero.  The implementation seems to  expect that if *lock is initially 0, then something running on the other core will soon set it to nonzero.  That's the "spin" in "spinlock".  HOWEVER, neither of the functions presented actually modify the value of *lock as I would expect them to do in order to implement a bona fide lock.  You can't really do that correctly without an atomic CAS (a.k.a. test/set) or an equivalent, but the implementation you show isn't even trying.  I don't think it actually provides any locking.
The __builtin_expect() macro is presumably intended as a configuration point where an atomic CAS could be inserted.

On some other processors, this
job would be done by a test_set instruction inside the while loop, but
here it is only reading the pointer value. Is this safe?

As far as I can tell, this function does not provide bona fide locking behavior.  So no.  Not even on a single-core machine.


What is the purpose of the memory barrier once the lock is acquired?


Locking has memory-ordering and visibility semantics.  Roughly speaking,

reads and writes of shared variables will not be reordered across either lock acquisition or lock release, and
writes to a shared variable by any thread that occur before that thread releases a given lock will be observable to any thread that subsequently acquires the same lock.

If the fence does it job then that will provide for those reordering and visibility requirements on the lock-acquisition side.  Even though the lock does not actually lock, providing these memory-ordering guarantees is much better than nothing.


I'm unclear about the comment inside the spin_lock_unsafe_blocking implementation. What do they mean by 'never
block'?


That's a weird usage of the word "block". I think it is supposed to mean that a thread running in that function will never be preempted.
